# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the request socket io

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am facing a problem when hosting an socket io application on heroku. The browser keep saying `Access to XMLHttpRequest at  from origin  has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`However, I already setup the server side with cors. Below I attach my server `index.js` .

[image]

Server `index.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("https");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

const server = http.createServer(app);
const user = [];

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: process.env.PORT || 5000,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});

const corsOptions ={
    origin: process.env.PORT || 5000, 
    credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

io.on("connection", (socket) => {

    user.push(socket.id);
   
    // console.log(`User Connected ${socket.id}`);

    socket.on("join_room", (data) =>{
        socket.join(data);
    })

    socket.on("send_message", (data) => { 

        let new_data = {user_id: data.id, msg: data.text};
      socket.to(data.room).emit("receive_message", new_data);
    })
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log("SERVER OK");
});
```

Please give me any hint since i tried so many solution that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

At the `origin` propery of `corsOptions` you have specified only the port, but you need the full origin (e.g. `http://localhost:5000`). So this might work:

```js
const corsOptions ={
    origin: "http://localhost:" + (process.env.PORT || 5000),
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//          whatever origin (protocol://full.domain.name:port) calling the server
    credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}
```

Comment: Still did not working..the cors still appear in browser sir